# lambda functions created in a for-loop being overwritten

Tags: python, lambda

Executing the following code

```py
# horizontals : list of functions
#     A list of spline functions
# vertical : function
#     Line function
# 
# All are given in the form f(x) = y

def mwe(horizontals, vertical):
    tangents = []
    for spline in horizontals:  
        x0, b = intersection(spline, vertical)  # Returns (float, float)

        m = float(spline(x, 1))
        tangent = lambda x: m * (x - x0) + b

        tangents.append(tangent)

        print(tangent(0))
        print(tangents[-1](0))


    print()
    for tangent in tangents:
        print(tangent(0))
```

results in this output:

```
715.2170619670379
715.2170619670379
851.5168419777629
851.5168419777629
992.2507908527389
992.2507908527389

992.2507908527389
992.2507908527389
992.2507908527389
```

I don't understand why all functions in the list are getting overwritten? Having only primitive datatypes (floats) in the expression should not lead to any reference problems, should it?

Edit: The code uses numpy/scipy for the splines if that matters.

Comment: this is a scoping issue with `for` loops in Python. `lambda` functions outlive the for loop. Initialize the `lambda` outside the for loop

Comment: Is the length of `horizontals` in the example 3? Somehow I would expect to see only 9 lines of output (+one empty line) instead of the 12.

Comment: Right, c&p error. Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What is the problem?

You can read it from the [official python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#id10), but in short

- For loop does not make a new variable scope.
- The variable in lamba is pointing to the scope of `mwe()`, and the value is only read when the lambda is called.

Consider this

```py
x = 5
def myfunc():
    print(x)
mylambda = lambda : print(x)

x = 99
myfunc()
mylambda()
```

what do you think will be printed to console? 99, right? *(Yes, it will be 99 in both cases)*.  See that lambdas behave exactly the same way as regular functions; If the variable is not defined in the function scope, python searches the variable from the parent scope. Notice that after a for loop like this

```py
for x in range(5)
    pass
print(x)
```

The value of `x` will be 5. So this is the reason why all the functions you created have the same value (the last one).

## So, how to solve this?

<sup>*Apologies for not copy-pasting your example code to my examples. I am writing the answer with my phone so it's easier to just write simplified examples. I hope you'll get the idea from these examples.*</sup>

There are three clean ways for the problem

### 1. Use variables local to lamba

That is, instead of

```py
a, b = 5, 8
func = lambda x: (x + a)/b
```

Use

```py
a, b = 5, 8
func = lambda x, a0=a, b0=b: (x + a0)/b0
```

The variables local to lambda have zero appended for clarity (will work with just the same variable names). Note that this is pretty much the same as

```py
a, b = 5, 8
def func(x, a0=a, b0=b): 
    return (x + a0)/b0
```

and it would be equally good option to use the `def func()` syntax inside the for loop.

### 2. Use a higher order function

By that I mean, since functions are objects (or: [first-class citizens](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_citizen)) in python, you can create a function that returns a function. Functions that take functions as arguments or return a function are called *higher order functions*. You can use this to create a higher order function:

```py
def get_func(a,b):
    return lambda x: (x+a)/b
```

or, why not even

```py
def get_func(a,b):
    def inner(x):
        return (x+a)/b
    return inner
```

and the later on just get functions in your loop with

```py
for i in range(5):
    a, b = get_params() # your logic here
    func = get_func(a,b)
```

This will work since the get_func has its' own scope.

### 3. use `partial()`

The builtin functools has a great helper function called partial which also does just what you want.

```py
from functools import partial

def base_func(x, a, b):
    return (x-a)/b

funcs = []
for i in range(5):
    a, b = get_params() # your logic here
    func = partial(base_func, a=a, b=b)
    funcs.append(func)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `lambda` is relying on the definition of `m`, `x0`, and `b` from the enclosing scope, but that dependency is loaded when the `lambda` is *executed*, not when it's *defined*. As such, you're using the values from the final loop in all of your `lambda`s. You need to store those values at definition time. The simplest approach is to make them default arguments for the `lambda` (argument defaults being bound at definition time):

```
    tangent = lambda x, m=m, x0=x0, b=b: m * (x - x0) + b
```

Comment: This is a very good solution - much better than mine. Good answer!

Comment: Wow, I've always thought that all but the "free" lambda parameters (in this case `x`) would be loaded and thus fixed on definition. Thanks, good lesson for today. :)

Comment: @sonovice: Yar. It follows the same rules as globals (just with another layer to check before looking at globals); if you do `x = 1`, define a function that uses `x` in its body, then do `x = 2`, the function will find `x` of `2` on future calls. Same behavior when reading a nested scope, whether it's global scope of an enclosing scope more closely linked than global.

Answer (score -1):

So, I think I found a way to get this to work.

```
# horizontals : list of functions
#     A list of spline functions
# vertical : function
#     Line function
# 
# All are given in the form f(x) = y

def mwe(horizontals, vertical):
    tangents = []
    for spline in horizontals:  
        x0, b = intersection(spline, vertical)  # Returns (float, float)

        m = float(spline(x, 1))
        exec("tangent = lambda x: {m} * (x - {x0}) + {b}".format(m=m,x0=x0,b=b))

        tangents.append(tangent)

        print(tangent(0))
        print(tangents[-1](0))


    print()
    for tangent in tangents:
        print(tangent(0))
```

exec gets a bad rep here on SO, but this works and I can't think of another way.

Comment: Thanks! Super hacky, but definitely a solution. If nothing "cleaner" comes up, I will probably use that.